# How to read a pdf document divided into columns (magazines and newspapers)?

Tags: python, pdf

Python 3.9.6

I have many medical journals. If I exported ones to text file, then I get the following: the text is presented in the form of three / two / one vertical columns (as the original pdf- text).

This doesn't allow reading data line by line: the text is shuffled from different columns into one sentence.

How to correctly read such data?

Answer (score 1):

There are several utilities that will reflow a page.

However they need to understand layouts such as a journal with fullwidth front matter followed by columns below. The alternative is to set regions of interest such that, for one journal you set the Top Matter Boundary Area and then have 2 (or more) different extraction sets below for the two three or more columns.

For Windows, Linux or Apple OS/X & M1 Arm-64 users there are complex tools such as https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/ that has a GUI for testing settings such as OCR etc.

[image][image]

Then the best options can be used from a python or other command line for batch runs. The alternative is to set your regions of interest such that for one journal you set the Top Matter Boundary Area and then have 2 (or more) different extraction sets below for the two three or more columns. Then use a Powerful Commercial Python tool such as to "Extract PDF text runs from a given clip region from a password protected PDF." one example with a command line demo version is at https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/cli/guides/pdf2text/usage/#example-3-extract-pdf-text-runs-from-a-given-clip-region-from-a-password-protected-pdf

If we dont set clip regions even with the best extractors it is easy for text to be seen out of order.

[image]